# Using gPhoto on iOS to communicate with digital cameras over USB

Tags: ios, bluetooth, usb, wifi, iokit

I want bidirectional USB communication between an iOS device and a digital camera using [gPhoto2](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/gphoto2/). gPhoto2 "abstracts communication ports and camera protocol, to allow a complete modularity."

Issues I've found:

- Apple's strict requirements for apps interfacing with the iOS hardware layer will enviably lead to rejection in the App Store approval process. [MFi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) may mediate this issue.
- Getting full access to the lightning/30-pin doc connector to send/receive USB packets may require a private iOS library such as IOKit, and that will get my binary rejected from the App Store.
- Connecting a camera via lightning/30-pin launches a PTPCamera-like task to allow the photo app to take over to import photos. That task must be killed get full USB access on OSX, so I'm guessing it's similar on iOS, and killing a task from an app's sandbox seems impossible.
- Compiling gPhoto2 for iOS is inherently difficult since I can't dynamically link the gphoto2 library, and thus I must compile it as a static library.

Those are some of the issues I've run into. Is this project worth pursuing? Do you think it's even possible?

Yes, I know there are other solutions, such as using a [wifi router](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833704138) or a custom built bluetooth module plugged into the camera to shuttle USB packets to and from the iOS device.

Comment: Did you manage to use gphoto2 on ios? I want to add DSLR support to my app.. I tried gphoto2 on osx but did not try to build and use it on ios.